# Start sidekiq from a rake task

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq, rake-task

I'm trying to start Sidekiq by executing a rake task. Here is my code.

```
namespace :sidekiq do
  task start: :environment do
    system "bundle exec sidekiq -C 'Path To Config File' -P 'Path For PID File' -d -L 'Path To Log File'"
  end
end
```

When I run the rake task using the command

> rake sidekiq:start

It starts sidekiq but rake task keeps waiting for response from Sidekiq. Any solution for this that my rake task doesn't wait for Sidekiq or it end when Sidekiq start.

Comment: That's weird. It should be daemonizing already.

Comment: Yeah you are right. It is daemonizing but the rake task keeps waiting for response.

Comment: Just add an & to the end.

Comment: I already tried that too. Result is the same.

Answer (score 1):

You should use foreman instead.

Add a Procfile file with your sidekiq line (something like):

```
worker: bundle exec sidekiq -C 'Path To Config File' -P 'Path For PID File' -d -L 'Path To Log File'
```

Also you might find useful this tutorial: 
http://blog.daviddollar.org/2011/05/06/introducing-foreman.html

Comment: Thanks for the solution but I already fixed that rake task with daemon. :)

Comment: @RqBukhari could you write your solution as an standalone answer?

Comment: @TetianaChupryna I added starting sidekiq to my deployment script (Capistrano). I am not using rake task anymore.

Comment: @TetianaChupryna if you have to do it using a rake task then you can try this

system "bundle exec sidekiq -P 'PATH TO PID FILE' -d -L 'PATH TO LOG FILE'"